# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TCPConnector.__init__' was never awaited self.connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=0, family=socket.AF_INET)

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, aiohttp

All of my discord bots stopped working all of a sudden. I didn't change anything in the code

error:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\http.py:789: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TCPConnector.**init**' was never awaited
> self.connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=0, family=socket.AF_INET)
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(564576757867563425)
    await channel.send("hello world")

client.run('__________________________')
```

Comment: Well, `__init__()` can't be an async function, but it appears you've somehow managed to end up with it changed to an async function in the aiohttp code. I suggest reinstalling aiohttp to get a fresh install, it's certainly not defined like that in the aiohttp package.